# How To Include "year" in REST call (best practices)

Tags: rest

I've got a REST call that looks something like `//.../rest/registered`.

I want to include the month and year of registration as part of the query.  I'm wondering if everyone has a standard way of doing this? I'm thinking something like
`.../2011/dec/rest/registered` but that seems strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is about resources and collections of resources. You may want to have a semantic URL pattern, but there is no need to have some subjective kind of beauty in it.

If your registrations are a top resource, and you have just one filter/sort criteria you can make it part of the path like

```
/rest/registration/2012
```

If you want to have multiple filtering criteria, and for pagination, you should use query parameters.

Note that usually the resources are named after nouns. So you would most likely have something like

```
 /rest/users/registered/2012
```

or

```
/rest/users/?state=registered&year=2012
```

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenating the year and month together in an integer:

```
/rest/registration/201212
```